# Trouble closing loops or creating a prompt to progress

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, prompt

I am struggling with the "while" command and loops in general. I am missing a stopping point but I don't know how to create one. I am trying to create a program to simulate a primitive stock option choice but it just cycles trough the first 2 loops without a stopping point. Any help would be appreciated.

```
selection = " "
while selection not in ("r","R","t","T"):
print("This program can operate in random mode (fluctuations will randomly occur) or it      can operate in test mode (fluctuations are fixed).")
print("(r)andom mode")
print("(t)est mode")
selection = input("Mode of operation:")
if selection not in ("r","R","t","T"):
    print("\nPlease select 'r' or 't' for mode selection\n")
elif (selection == "r"):
    print("Random mode enabled")
    n = random.randrange(1,101)
    selection = " "
    while selection not in ("1","2","3"):
        print("\tInvestment options:")
        print("(1)Fly-By-Night Investments (FBN): high risk, high potential returns")
        print("(2)Blue Chips INC. (BCI): moderate risk, good potential yearly returns")
        print("(3)Slow-And-Steady-Corp. (SNS), mature industry stock: no risk but low returns")
        selection = input("Please enter your investment option 1, 2, or 3:")
        if selection not in ("1","2","3"):
            print("\nPlease enter an investment option from the menu using 1, 2, or 3 as valid selections:\n")
```

The random and test mode come later in the program but I wanted to show the loops where I dont have a stopping point anywhere. It just cycles through the two.

Comment: use "break" inside the ifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck in an infinite loop because you redefine `selection`.

```
selection = ''
while selection.lower() not in ("r","t"):
    print("This program can operate in random mode (fluctuations will randomly occur) or it can operate in test mode (fluctuations are fixed).")
    print("(r)andom mode")
    print("(t)est mode")
    selection = input("Mode of operation:")
    if selection.lower() not in ("r","t"):
         print("\nPlease select 'r' or 't' for mode selection\n")
    elif (selection.lower() == "r"):
        print("Random mode enabled")
        n = random.randrange(1,101)
        selection = '' # redefined here
        while selection not in ("1","2","3"): 
            print("\tInvestment options:")
            print("(1)Fly-By-Night Investments (FBN): high risk, high potential returns")
            print("(2)Blue Chips INC. (BCI): moderate risk, good potential yearly returns")
            print("(3)Slow-And-Steady-Corp. (SNS), mature industry stock: no risk but low returns")
            selection = input("Please enter your investment option 1, 2, or 3:")
            if selection not in ("1","2","3"):
                print("\nPlease enter an investment option from the menu using 1, 2, or 3 as valid selections:\n")
```

Note how you use `selection` again. Once it hits the inner `while` loop, `selection` becomes either 1, 2, or 3 (or anything else), but most likely, not 'r' or 't'. Thus, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. To prevent this, use two different variables per loop.

```
selection = ''
while selection.lower() not in ("r","t"):
    print("This program can operate in random mode (fluctuations will randomly occur) or it can operate in test mode (fluctuations are fixed).")
    print("(r)andom mode")
    print("(t)est mode")
    selection = input("Mode of operation:")
    if selection.lower() not in ("r","t"):
         print("\nPlease select 'r' or 't' for mode selection\n")
    elif (selection.lower() == "r"):
        print("Random mode enabled")
        n = random.randrange(1,101)
        investmentChoice = ''
        while investmentChoice not in ("1","2","3"): 
            print("\tInvestment options:")
            print("(1)Fly-By-Night Investments (FBN): high risk, high potential returns")
            print("(2)Blue Chips INC. (BCI): moderate risk, good potential yearly returns")
            print("(3)Slow-And-Steady-Corp. (SNS), mature industry stock: no risk but low returns")
            investmentChoice = input("Please enter your investment option 1, 2, or 3:")
            if investmentChoice not in ("1","2","3"):
                print("\nPlease enter an investment option from the menu using 1, 2, or 3 as valid selections:\n")
```